# Cannot add multiple css file in tiles with struts 2

Tags: css, struts2, tiles

I'm working with framework struts 2 and use Tiles in Struts to design a view. But I get an error that does not fix it! Although I have searched a lot on google.

I haved file a tiles.xml:

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="baseLayoutAdmin" template="/admin/BaseLayoutAdmin.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value=""  />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/admin/Header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/admin/Menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/admin/Footer.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="pageCss" type="strings" value="{'stylesheets/theme.css','lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css','lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'}" />
        <!--<put-attribute name="cssTheme" value="stylesheets/theme.css" />
        <put-attribute name="cssbootstrap" value="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <put-attribute name="cssFont" value="lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"/>
        <put-attribute name="cssJquery" value="lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="strings"/>-->
    </definition>
    <definition name="/admin/index.tiles" extends="baseLayoutAdmin">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Home Page News Online Manager" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/admin/index.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

In file BaselayoutAdmin.jsp, I used:

```
<s:set var="pageCssArray"><tiles:getAsString name="pageCss" /></s:set>
        <s:iterator value="%{#pageCssArray}">
            <s:set var="CurrentCss"><s:property/></s:set>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<s:url value='%{#CurrentCss}'/>" />
        </s:iterator>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" /></title>
```

to get css file from tiles.

But when I deploy project then following error appears:

> undeploy?path=/NewsOnline
>   OK - Undeployed application at context path /NewsOnline
>   In-place deployment at C:\Users\san\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NewsOnline\build\web
>   deploy?  config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fsan%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext5234232918126270598.xml&path=/NewsOnline
>   FAIL - Deployed application at context path /NewsOnline but context failed to start
>   C:\Users\san\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NewsOnline\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1086: The module has not been deployed.
>   See the server log for details.
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

If I delete:

```
<put-attribute name="pageCss" type="strings" value="{'stylesheets/theme.css','lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css','lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'}" />
```

Then it works fine. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: Post your fix as an answer to help future visitors.

Comment: the error is due to the file (js, css, js) to a folder in the admin (I define to separate admin and user files). if you leave them outside of webpage folder there will be no error occurs! 
and you do not need to add css or javascript files into another file tiles.xml. You can leave them on file baseLayout.jsp files inherit from it will receive css and js. I'm not good at english use google translate hope people sympathize!

Comment: That's not an answer, is a comment. Please post it as an answer to your own question

Answer (score 0):

the error is due to the file (js, css, js) to a folder in the admin (I define to separate admin and user files). if you leave them outside of webpage folder there will be no error occurs! and you do not need to add css or javascript files into another file tiles.xml. You can leave them on file baseLayout.jsp files inherit from it will receive css and js. I'm not good at english use google translate hope people sympathize!